# Reference semantics of conditional operator

Tags: c#

I was playing around with using *an lvalue* as a result of conditional operator (`cond ? expr1 : expr2`).

Consider following example

```
class /*(1)*/ Value {
    public int MagicNumber { get; private set; } = 0;
    public void Increment() {
        /* magical code, that modifies MagicNumber */
    }
}

void Main()
{
    Value v1, v2;
    /*(2)*/ bool condition = /*...*/;
    (condition ? v1 : v2).Increment(); // (3)
}
```

Now, I would suspect, based on value of `condition`, that either `v1` or `v2` gets incremented. That actually is the case, as long as `Value` (`(1)`) is class. Once I change it to `struct`, it becomes *Value type* and line `(3)` does nothing (I would suspect because either `v1` or `v2` is copied, incremented and discarded). Up to this, it makes sense. The weird behavior begins once `(2)` (`condition`) is known at compile time (for example by defining it `const bool`). Then some optimalization comes to play and one of `v1` or `v2` is actually incremented in place.

My question is, what should be the correct behavior of conditional operator in following case

```
(condition ? v1 : v2).Increment();
```

once `v1` and `v2` is `struct`. Should it really depend on `condition` being compile-time constant?

Comment: You are correct that when it's a struct it's creating a copy.  That's why mutable structs are evil.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/441309/why-are-mutable-structs-evil

Comment: The C# compiler does not perform a lot of optimizations, but it does tackle a const expression like this.  The quirky behavior is why you usually see "don't mutate a struct!" advice posted at SO.  Not that pretty, value types are a leaky abstraction in C#.  I think you should click the [New Issue button](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues) and let the Microsoft engineers weigh on the matter.  I doubt they'll fix it, but who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested, I've sent bug report to the Microsoft and it turned out, that standard does not explicitly says whether result of conditional operator is r-value (value) or l-value (variable). By transitivity of other things in the standard, it seems, that result [should be an r-value](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/17756#issuecomment-286052972).

It was decided that the bug should be fixed and the fix is already on it's way.